# Is there a way to make an Android application start with the Android WLAN settings activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

For the project I'm working on there's a requirement to start our Android application with the Android WLAN settings activity, without going first through our initial Activity - basically we don't want to show our application until after the user sets up the WIFI. Do you have any suggestions on how to implement something like this?

Thanks,
Mihai

Comment: u want to keep your app hidden with installing it? if yes , why would u do that

Comment: simply keep ur app icon transparent. and using a receiver check if the user has worked on his wifi setting and then call the intent filter

Comment: @TerrilThomas yes, something like that worked, but now it's irrelevant as we don't need this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

//Activity transfer to wifi settings

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: That is the first step in order to show the WIFI settings activity, but the app still opens it's first activity from which you do the call to settings. In the end, I think I managed to do this by having the activity with invisible layout, but now we don't need that anymore.